# How to make a .jar file with multiple classes in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-15

Suppose I have multiple classes I want in a .jar. How would I do that in IntelliJ?

**Edit: This is just a normal IDEA project. All of the classes compile properly. I want all classes to be in the JAR.**

Comment: Please provide more info. Is your project a "normal" IDEA project, or using a framework such as maven or gradle? Do you already have classes that are compiling properly in your project? Do you want all classes, or just a subset, to be in the JAR?

Comment: Package it? It's not clear what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

You can check all your classes which will be in *.jar in Intellij
`ctrl+alt+shift+s` (Project settings) -> Artifacts

There you can choose  artifacts settings (included classes also)

then, to build package from artifact:

`Build -> Build Artifact` -> choose created artifact
then, in out folder you get your *jar (or another - which you choose in artifact) package

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to File -> Project Structure -> Artifacts
2. Click on the green plus sign -> JAR -> modules with dependencies

   The module is your entire project.
3. Specify your main class. Then click OK
4. Check the "include in project build" box. Then click OK
5. You can use the terminal of IntelliJ to execute the file

   ```
   java -jar "the path to the Jar file"
   ```